# React Native ListView won't reach the bottom

Tags: listview, react-native

This might sound like a careless mistake, but I've tried everything I can think of.

I am using `ListView` for a large set of data. There are approximately 150 rows to render. The list scrolls fine but it just won't reach the bottom. It stops at row 142 and I can clearly see there are still more rendered rows through the bounce animation.

Here is my code:

```
public render() {

    const scrollView = {
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'handled' as any,
        alwaysBounceVertical: true,
        removeClippedSubviews: false,
    };

    const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

        return (<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <ListView
                        { ...scrollView }
                        style={{ width: windowWidth }}
                        initialListSize={1}
                        pageSize={5}
                        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                        renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
                        renderRow={this._renderRow}
                        />
                    </View>
        );
```

I have tried setting a specific height to the `ListView`'s parent view, the scroll stops at the exact same spot, so it's not a frame height issue.

What could be the issue here?

p/s: currently tested on iOS

Edit 1:
Adding `paddingBottom` to `contentContainerStyle` on `ListView` will allow me to scroll to the bottom. But the value of that padding is undeterminable on different devices.

Comment: Do you add anything else besides `paddingBottom` to the `contentContainerStyle` prop?

Comment: @max23_ no that's the only thing i added. `contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 500}}`

Comment: Not sure but are you using this as the app's entry component or it is used as a sub component in another component (parent)?

Comment: @max23_ no, the `<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>` you see is the top most parent.

Comment: I mean like is this component(class or function) is the entry point of your app (where you define `AppRegistry.registerComponent('myProject', () => yourComponent)`? Or you are calling this component (e.g. DataList.js) in another component (e.g. Main.js).

Comment: @max23_ that would be the latter.

Comment: I see. My guess is that the problem might be due to how you include this ListView component in another component's render().